# pass a useCallback function to Formik innerRef to listen for state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm wondering if anyone has experience passing a callback from `useCallback` to Formik's `innerRef` prop. I haven't used this hook very much so I'm still trying to understand it a little better.

Currently, I have the following, and it works for triggering Formik submission from outside the `<Formik>` component, but I'm struggling with updating `isSavingDisabled` based on changes to Formik's `isValid` state, because React refs don't trigger `useEffect` when specified as a dependency (as noted in React docs).

```
const MyModal = () => {

  const [isSavingDisabled, setSavingDisabled] = useState( false )
  const formikRef = useRef()

  const doSave = () => {
    if ( formikRef.current ) {
      formikRef.current.handleSubmit()
    }
  }

  return (
    <Modal>
      <ModalHeader>My Modal Header</ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>
        <Formik innerRef={formikRef} {...formikProps}>
          { /* Form body */ }
        </Formik>
      </ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter>
        <Button disabled={isSavingDisabled} onClick={doSave}>
          Save
        </Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

I need to: 1) preserve a reference to `handleSubmit` so I can call it from outside the `<Formik>` component, but also 2) listen for changes to the `isValid` property of Formik's state so that I can disable the save button whenever `isValid === false`.

I've seen that `useCallback`, possibly paired with `useState`, can be used instead of `useRef`, but I'm running into a render loop. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching and reading, I found this: https://github.com/formium/formik/discussions/2746 which discusses using the `useFormik` hook with the `FormikProvider` context provider. This gives me what I need and I wish this usage were properly documented. :)

Comment: Thank you! Using `FormikProvider` did the trick!!